# Add custom hook to Gitlab installed with Docker

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, gitlab

I installed gitlab on my server using Docker.
I want to access the gitlab local repositories so I can create custom hooks for every project.

The problem is that I can't find the gitlab local repositories anywhere on my server.

Comment: how are you running the docker container?  Can you share the command.  If you didn't use volume mounts then it's possible the repositories are inside the docker container (not what you want).

Comment: I used this command to install gitlab "$ sudo docker run --detach --name gitlab \
 --hostname gitlab.example.com \
 --publish 30080:30080 \
         --publish 30022:22 \
 --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'http://gitlab.example.com:30080'; gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port']=30022;" \
 gitlab/gitlab-ce:9.1.0-ce.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current run command is:

```
docker run --detach --name gitlab \
   --hostname gitlab.example.com \
   --publish 30080:30080 \
   --publish 30022:22 \
   --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'gitlab.example.com:30080';; gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port']=30022;" \
   gitlab/gitlab-ce:9.1.0-ce.0"
```

This command doesn't include any external volume mounts, so I would suggest creating a local data directory for GitLab, and including volume mounts so that GitLab uses local storage for the backing database and repositories.

*Note that if you have created content in your running instance (that doesn't have volume mounts) then it may be lost if the container is deleted.*

Create the local directories (you can use a different path):

```
mkdir -p /gitlab/data
mkdir -p /gitlab/config
mkdir -p /gitlab/logs
```

Add volume mounts to your docker command:

```
docker run --detach --name gitlab \
   --hostname gitlab.example.com \
   --publish 30080:30080 \
   --publish 30022:22 \
   --volume /gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
   --volume /gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
   --volume /gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
   --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'gitlab.example.com:30080';; gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port']=30022;" \
   gitlab/gitlab-ce:9.1.0-ce.0"
```

This will create persistent volumes for your gitlab server.

After you start the server and create a project you will find your repositories in the data directory.